# what does "0" stand for in conditional operator?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
  i = (i == array.length-1) ? 0 : i + 1;
```

As I understand, the conditional operator works as follows:

```
booleanCondition ? executeThisPartIfBooleanConditionIsTrue : executeThisPartIfBooleanConditionIsFalse
```

What does 0 execute?

Comment: `if(i == array.length-1) { i = 0; } else { i = i + 1; }`

Comment: post full code, please

Comment: Not really clear what you question is - could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: `( condition) ?  result for true : result for false` ... resulting in a value. That is all there is to this.

Comment: It is not about **execution**. The ternary operator computes a **value**. The two different "branches" represent the **expressions** that are returned, based on the condition.

Comment: @GhostCat  Strickly speaking this is NOT a duplicate since it is "what is the "0" called" not what is a ternary or conditional operator

Comment: The point is that the OP has a wrong understanding of ternary operators. There is no execution here. Just expressions evaluating to values. So linking to "what are ternary expressions" seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the "positive conditional test result" really has a formal name.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

> ?:      Ternary (shorthand for 
>           if-then-else statement)

using a boolean example

```
isConditionTrue = 1 == 2 ? true : false;
```

this in your example

```
i = (i == array.length-1) ? 0 : i + 1;
```

has the same result as

```
if (i == array.length-1)
{i= 0 ;}
else {i = i + 1;}
```

Comment: Despite the down-vote I stand by my answer of "it really has no formal name" for the positive conditional result.

Answer (score -1):

This is known as the Elvis Operator (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator]) and given the following example:

```
x = A ? B : C;
```

... it means that if A is evaluated to 'true' than x gets assigned the value B otherwise it gets assigned the value C.

In your example it means, that if 'i==array.length-1' then 'i' is set to '0' otherwise 'i' is set to 'i+1'.